# Multiple testing with Wilcoxon signed rank test with set maximum length

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, bonferroni

I'm essentially performing this test with the Java Apache math3 method which only allows lengths up to 30. My pairs will have a length of maximum 2048. I will be testing for an increase (combination of this test and another small comparison). My solution currently is to partition my datasets into 30 length subsets. I have researched multiple testing and it seems that Bonferroni is a popular option but struggles under larger amounts of datasets. I wonder if the fact that my amount of datasets is 2048 / 30 = 68.27 -> 69 datasets if that will be small enough to be significant still.

That is my question, is 69 datasets too much to test for significance using Bonferroni multiple testing?

Comment: What do mean by _length_?  Is it the number of pairs?  If the software limits you to a sample size of 30 you are using the wrong software.

Comment: Yes, I mean a number of pairs up to a maximum of 30 for calculating exact P values. Their explanation is that anything over 30 number of pairs will be too computationally expensive to calculate. Line 288 here https://home.apache.org/~luc/commons-math-3.6-RC2-site/jacoco/org.apache.commons.math3.stat.inference/WilcoxonSignedRankTest.java.html

They also offer approximation which would allow me to run 2048 at once but this is for a critical application.

Comment: The easy solution is to get fast approximate p-values for $n > 30$.  At those sample sizes the approximation is adequate.  Also see how to do this with the [proportional odds model](https://fharrell.com/post/pair) which yields accurate $p$-values at almost any sample size with excellent handling of arbitrarily many ties in the data.